# Constructing XML tree in Python from filtered dataframe

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, dictionary

How to filter Dataframe and use them to construct a xml tree in Python?

I have a data frame like below:

| DisplayName | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| firstname | givenName |
| lastname | sn |

I need to map the column 1 and column2 as value in below xml like below. Format should be displayname = attribute. I just need to map the firstname and lastname.

```
<root nsp="suan2.0" host="1" id="tools">
    <config alias="/ki">
            <Element name="elmap">
                <Value>firstname=givenName</Value>
                <Value>lastname=sn</Value>
            </Element>
            <Element name="category">
                <Value>ADD</Value>
            </Element>
    </config>
</root>
```

I need some help regarding the df filtration and then later construct the above xmltree  element tag with content "elmap" which is constructed dynamically while other tags can remain static in xml

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add your attempted python code and describe any issue found.

Answer (score 0):

Small XML, but a lot steps:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

# Build the XML Frame
r = """<root nsp="suan2.0" host="1" id="tools"></root>"""
c = """<config alias="/ki"></config>"""
e = """<Element name="elmap"></Element>"""
root = ET.fromstring(r)
config = ET.fromstring(c)
elem = ET.fromstring(e)
root.append(config)
config.append(elem)

# Concat the cell value and create XML from pd
lst1 = ['firstname','lastname']
lst2 = ['givenName','sn']

df = pd.DataFrame({'DisplayName': lst1, 'Attribute': lst2})

df['Value'] = df['DisplayName'].map(str) + '=' + df['Attribute'].map(str)
pdxml = df.to_xml()

# Append values from df to the XML Frame
root_pd = ET.fromstring(pdxml)
for val in root_pd.iter('Value'):
    elem.append(val)

# Extend the XML
v = """<Value></Value>"""
addE = ET.Element('Element')
addE.attrib['name'] = "category"
valE = ET.fromstring(v)
valE.text = 'ADD'
addE.append(valE)

for conf in root.iter('config'):
    conf.append(addE)

# Pretty Print and write to file
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree, space="  ")
tree.write("test.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8", )

# Result for Shell only
ET.dump(tree)
```

Output:

```
<root nsp="suan2.0" host="1" id="tools">
  <config alias="/ki">
    <Element name="elmap">
      <Value>firstname=givenName</Value>
      <Value>lastname=sn</Value>
    </Element>
    <Element name="category">
      <Value>ADD</Value>
    </Element>
  </config>
</root>
```